# Using the Embed_a_Survey_Link email template to sund survey's on cases. Can I add the case fields?

Tags: salesforce-survey, lightning-email-template

We are using surveys to send our customers CSAT upon a case is closed.
In the Embed_a_Survey_Link (standard tempalte), we want to modify the subject, and inlcude any identification from the case.
But there is no option to select the case in the select merge field
[![enter image description here][1]][1]

only these options
[![enter image description here][2]][2]

Any idea how can I modify the bubject of the email before sending the invitaiton ?
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TbfBN.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UE5Tl.png

Comment: Did you get any solution on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I ended up doing is: Upon closing a case,I build everything using a flow:
[image]

Get all the relevant objects, create the needed survey invitation and subject, and eventually send an email with the format I want.

Comment: N.B. It would be helpful if you explained how the Email Alert / Email Template was constructed as you need both Case merge fields and the link to the Survey (which is not a Case field).  What was the target object for the email alert?